# Question on Haskell syntax. Continuation monad example

Tags: haskell

trying to understand [Continuation monad examples](https://jsdw.me/posts/haskell-cont-monad/) implemented in Haskell.

**Question**:

where does `fn` in 1st line of `goto` on the right - in `out fn` part comes from? Is it some omitted argument or some destructuring of `out` [same with `out (fn, num)` in `gotoC`]?
Imagine you explain this for a mainstream language coder (JS, Java, Python)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Cont  as C

goto = C.callCC $ \out -> let fn = out fn
                          in return fn

gotoC = C.callCC $ \out -> let fn num = out (fn, num)
                           in return (fn, 0)
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Imagine you explain this for a mainstream language coder (JS, Java, Python)

You can't. You really can't, because you really couldn't write that line of code in Java.

```
let fn = out fn
in return fn
```

`fn` isn't a hidden variable or anything. It's declared right there. Its value is `out fn`. The variable `fn` is defined in terms of itself. Sounds ridiculous, but we do this all the time in Haskell. For instance,

```
let xs = 1 : xs in ...
```

this is an infinite list. The variable `xs` is defined to be itself with a `1` prepended to the front. The only<sup>[1]</sup> value for which this is true is the list of an infinite number of ones. Effectively, we've found a *fixed point*.

So back to your example,

```
goto = C.callCC $ \out -> let fn = out fn
                          in return fn
```

The type of [`callCC`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:callCC) is

```
callCC :: ((a -> ContT r m b) -> ContT r m a) -> ContT r m a
```

We're not doing anything crazy with monad transformers here, so let's drop the `m`.

```
callCC :: ((a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r a) -> Cont r a
```

Therefore, the type of `out` must be `out :: a -> Cont r b` (for some `r`, a`, and` b`). Now, we wrote

```
let fn = out fn in return fn
```

and this whole expression has type `Cont r a`. Hence, `return fn` has type `Cont r a`, and `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`, so `fn :: a`.

We apply `out` to `fn`, so

```
out :: a -> Cont r b
fn :: a
out fn :: Cont r b
```

And `fn = out fn`, hence `a ~ Cont r b`. So `fn :: Cont r b`. That is, `fn` is a continuation which is defined to be `out` applied to itself.

If you don't like the recursion, you can use [`fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix) instead.

```
let fn = fix out in return fn
```

In Haskell, in general but *especially* with advanced monads like `Cont`, you have to trust your types a bit. `Cont` is going to involve a lot of fancy recursive shenanigans like this, so being able to identify a value by its type (and trust that it works consistently with its type) is important.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Well, the *least-defined* value. In this case, I believe it is truly the only fixed point, but in some situations there can be multiple. See [denotational semantics](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) for more.

Comment: Silvio special thanks for such a detailed answer. made it clear. i play with this article converting it to scala for myself. that point at the end of the article made me stop

Comment: Using `fix`, could we have just written `return (fix out)` instead of using the `let` expression to define `fn`?

Comment: @chepner Yes. (filler)

Answer (score 2):

`out` is a continuation generated by `callCC`. Wherever `callCC` is used (by which we mean, wherever `goto` is used), a function that captures the rest of the code is generated. Calling out with some function `f` means to execute the code in `out`, then (probably) calling `f`.

Writing `fn = out fn` "computes" the *fixed point* of `out`: when you call `fn`, you do whatever `out` does, then continue by (maybe) executing `fn` again. (But only because Haskell is non-strict; you don't need to evaluate `out fn` until you actually evaluate `fn`.) So `goto` is essentially an infinite loop, *unless* the code generated for `out` allows you to *not* execute `fn` at some point.

In a language like Python, the same idea might be implemented with infinite `while` loops with explicit `break` statements. Adapting the `gotoEx1` example in the linked post. (This is not necessarily a mechanical translation of any `Cont` value to Python, just something that captures the
idea of continuations without using functions.)

```py
def gotoEx1():
    marker1 = True
    while True:
        print "one"
        marker2 = True
        while marker2:
            print "two"
            x = random.randint(0, 2)
            if num < 1:
                # Break out of the inner loop,
                # allowing the outer loop to resume from the top
                marker2 = False
            elif num < 2:
                # Do nothing, allowing the inner loop to resume from
                # the top
                pass
            else:
                # Clear both flags, allowing both the inner
                # and outer loops to terminate
                marker1 = False
                marker2 = False
                print("done")
```

Comment: cheers. this brings new details into the picture.

Comment: Consider this the viewpoint of someone else who could never have defined `Cont` or `callCC` themselves, but has a vague understanding of how the resulting definitions behave :)

Comment: well, yep. i'm digesting this article for the 2nd day converting it to scala for myself. quite  a mind boggling stuff :)